# How can I make a multiple-column output with 'awk' command?

Tags: awk

I am using an 'awk' command like below, which prints the 4th columns of all .out files containing 'cake':

`awk '/cake/{print $4}' ./*/*.out`

My output is a column, say:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

How can I reformat this to something that looks like:

```
1 4  
2 5  
3 6
```

or

```
1 3 5
2 4 6
```

i.e. have a set number of column elements (3 and 2 in the above cases).

Better yet, can I make it spit out the output as a csv file within the same command?

Thank you.

Comment: This might help: [In bash how can I split a column in several column of fixed dimension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33523888/3776858)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with `awk` itself, but I prefer `pr` for this

```
$ # -2 is number of columns needed
$ # -s option specifies delimiter, default is tab
$ seq 6 | pr -2ts','
1,4
2,5
3,6
$ seq 6 | pr -3ts','
1,3,5
2,4,6

$ # you can also change horizontal/vertical order
$ seq 6 | pr -3ats','
1,2,3
4,5,6
```

Comment: With long options: `seq 6 | pr --columns 2 --omit-header --separator=','`

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat tst.awk
{ a[NR] = $0 }
END {
    OFS = ","
    numCols = (numCols ? numCols : 1)
    numRows = ceil(NR / numCols)
    for ( rowNr=1; rowNr<=numRows; rowNr++ ) {
        for ( colNr=1; colNr<=numCols; colNr++ ) {
            idx = rowNr + ( (colNr - 1) * numRows )
            printf "%s%s", a[idx], (colNr<numCols ? OFS : ORS)
        }
    }
}
function ceil(x, y){y=int(x); return(x>y?y+1:y)}

$ awk -v numCols=2 -f tst.awk file
1,4
2,5
3,6

$ awk -v numCols=3 -f tst.awk file
1,3,5
2,4,6
```

Note that the above will work even if your number of input rows isn't an exact multiple of the number of columns you want (note that there's 3 comma-separated fields even in the lines with empty fields):

```
$ seq 10 | awk -v numCols=3 -f tst.awk
1,5,9
2,6,10
3,7,
4,8,
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/56725768/1745001 for how to do the opposite, i.e. generate a number of columns given a specified number of rows.